# Delphi XE Firemonkey mobile app - Como diminuir o tamanho de uma imagem?

Tags: delphi, mobile, imagem, bitmap

O problema que enfrento é que permito ao usuário a inserção de uma imagem de sua galeria do dispositivo móvel, algumas imagens tem tamanho demasiadamente grande para serem gravados em banco levando em consideração a maravilhosa qualidade de sinal 3g. A solução provisória que encontrei foi gerar um thumbnail com dimensões pré definidas. Ex:250,250. A imagem fica razoável, porém, algumas fotos não possuem suas dimensões exatas em x e y e por esse motivo o componente cria uma moldura com aparência esquisita. Em relação ao tamanho do arquivo não ultrapassa os 110kb, o problema é realmente esta moldura. Alguém já enfrentou a mesma dificuldade?

Comment: Qual o componente que esta usando para carregar a imagem ?

Comment: uso um TImage @JúniorMoreira

Answer (score 1):

O erro acontece porque o componente TImage está configurado para receber uma imagem quadrada, e eventualmente são enviadas imagens no modo retrato/paisagem (retangulares). Uma forma de resolver isso serial obrigar o usuário a recortar a imagem antes dela ser carregada no TImage para um formato quadrado, eliminando assim as bordas.

Comment: boa alternativa, vou implementar e depois respondo se obtive sucesso. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Evandro,

Tive esse mesmo problema em um app que estava desenvolvendo. Eu permitia que os usuários enviassem uma foto para colocar como imagem de perfil deles.
Como resolvi?

**1)** Coloquei um TLayout no form com alinhamento Center e tamanho 300 x 300 (o importante é deixar largura e altura iguais, formando um quadrado)

**2)** Dentro desse TLayout, coloquei um TImageViewer com alinhamento Client (ocupando todo o TLayout)

**3)** Carrego a imagem a ser tratada dentro do TImageViewer, dessa forma:

```
ImageViewer1.Bitmap.Assign(imagem);
```

**4)** Ajustei a propriedade BitmapScale do TImageViewer conforme desejado (zoom na imagem)

**5)** Por fim, depois que o usuário ajustou a imagem como queira (arrastando com o dedo), coloquei um botão na parte de baixo do form com o seguinte código:

```
var 
imagem : TBitmap;
...
    imagem := Layout1.MakeScreenshot;
...
```

Isso faz com que o Delphi crie um "print" da imagem que o usuário está vendo na tela, e salva esse "print" na variável imagem.

**6)** Depois disso é só tratar a variável imagem como desejar! ;)

Espero ter ajudado.

PS: Depois que deu tudo certo, você pode sofisticar seu TImageViewer para o usuário dar zoom na foto fazendo movimento de "pinça" com os dedos, pode colocar opção para girar a imagem, e por aí vai.